# Calculate the sequence of continuous numbers

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the amount of continuous digits on a given number. IE Number 7 has 7 continuous digits, while number 10 has 11 continuous digits. Here's an image to depict the problem

[image]

The first row shows the sequence and the second one shows the amount of numbers this has.

This has to be on python, but any ideas will help

Comment: "Continuous digits" has little meaning. Presumably, you want the total number of digits in the sequence from 1 to n.

Comment: Hint: the requested function is piecewise linear: from 1 to 9, one digit per number; from 10 to 99, two digits per number; from 100 to 999, three digits; and so on.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I want. Sorry I translated the question incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at understanding your question.

```python
def continuous_digits(x):
    count = 0
    for i in range(1,x+1):
        s = str(i)
        count += len(s)
    return count

# Test the function
for i in range(7,12):
    print(f'Number: {i}: Continuous Digit Length: {continuous_digits(i)}')
```

The output:

```
Number: 7: Continuous Digit Length: 7
Number: 8: Continuous Digit Length: 8
Number: 9: Continuous Digit Length: 9
Number: 10: Continuous Digit Length: 11
Number: 11: Continuous Digit Length: 13
```

Comment: I was able to Figur it out. But this works perfectly. If somebody else is looking for the answer this one works just fine

Comment: Thanks! Could you mark my answer as accepted? I'm a new user and could use the rep.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a string with all the digits and get its length (but that's not very efficient):

```
n = 103
r = len("".join(map(str,range(1,n+1))))  # 201
```

Alternatively what you can do it compute the number of 1-digit, 2-digit, ... x-digit values that are below n.  You can figure out these numbers starting with the largest number of digit (which you can obtain using the base 10 logarithm).

```
from math import log

d = int(log(n,10))
r = (d+1)*(n+1-10**d) + sum((i+1)*9*10**i for i in range(d)) # 201
```